# WordPress: Number of posts by author

Tags: wordpress, author

How can I show how many posts an author has made on a WordPress site?

e.g.

```
<div class="avatar-card-content">
    <h3><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h3>
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>0 <span>Posts</span></li>
    </ul>
</div
```

What would I put in the place of the '0' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?php the_author_posts() ?>` will do it. From wp-includes/author-template.php

`get_the_author_posts()` to return the value, `the_author_posts()` to echo it.